# Urban Fantasy about female half-elves being hunted for their dormant powers

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I remember the following points about the story:

- It's an urban fantasy
- It was a book with vampires and elves
- The main character was some kind of elf
- People would get ear transplants to look like elves
- The main character had a friend who was a kelpie
- People that were half elf and half human seemed to be desirable
- The plot seemed to revolve around a guy hunting down female half-elves to perform a ritual through which he got their dormant powers

Comment: Do you remember when you may have read it? When it may have been published? This helps narrow down the book.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember when I read this or when it was published. I remember looking for it about 3 years ago with no success, so it must have been before that.

Answer (score 6):

It is called *The Bitter Seed of Magic* by Suzanne McLeod. Apparently, it is the third book in her *Spellcrackers.com* series. It is indeed an urban fantasy with, among others, fae and vampires. The main character, Genny Taylor, is sidhe fae and one of her friends, Tavish, is a kelpie. The plot in this particular book does revolve around faelings (half-human/half-fae) disappearing.

[Suzanne McLeod - Books](http://www.spellcrackers.com/books.html#anchor_334):

> On the surface, Genny's life seems ripple-free right now. Finn, her sexy boss and -- well, Genny's not sure what else she wants him to be -- has stopped pushing for a decision on their relationship. The seductive vampire Malik al-Khan has vanished back into the shadows. And the witches have declared her no longer a threat. But unless Genny can find a way to break the fertility curse afflicting London's fae, she knows this is just the lull before the magical storm.
>
> Then a faeling -- a teenage girl -- is fished out of the River Thames, dead and bound with magic, and Genny is called into investigate. As she digs through the clues, her search takes a sinister and dangerous turn, exposing age-old secrets that might be better left buried. Then another faeling disappears, and Genny finds herself in a race against time to save the faeling and stop the curse from claiming its next victim -- herself!

Answer (score 3):

Could this be one of the *October Daye* novels?  They are an urban fantasy series with a female half-elven protagonist.

From [the author's Web site](http://seananmcguire.com/toby.php):

> Faerie has always been with us. The fairy tales, ballads, and folklore of the mortal world are only shadows of the true, sometimes terrible reality of the fae. They survive in secrecy, keeping their Courts in the places where the light doesn't fall, existing in parallel to the world we know. They aren't human. They don't want to be. But sometimes they take human lovers, and sometimes, those unions are fertile ones. Changelings aren't stolen children; they're mortal halfbreeds born where the fae and human worlds collide, never able to fully belong to either, outsiders from birth.
>
> October Daye knows how cruel Faerie can be to its changeling children. Born in San Francisco and carried to the Summerlands by her pureblood mother when she was just a child, she was raised in a world that never seemed capable of understanding her. She ran away the moment the opportunity presented itself, only to find that the human world wasn't any better.

Comment: Sadly, this is not the book I am looking for :( Thank you very much though!